# Unpredictable multiple homophony of Chinese characters

Tags: learning-methods, vocabulary, chinese, l2-acquisition, memorization

I look for a strategy to deal with this lexical issue of the Chinese language, and so memorize the right pronunciation(s) correctly

Comment: This is way too broad. There are numerous techniques for Chinese LL. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @bytebuster As the question title says, this is not about the pronunciation of Chinese characters in general, but about those that have more than one pronunciation. That's definitely a minority (unlike Japanese kanji). Still, it would be nice if GJC could expand about on this in the question text.